# How to create an uncover effect top to bottom w/ drawtext?

Tags: ffmpeg

I seek to create an uncover effect top to bottom w/ drawtext. And the options to define the start time/delay and speed.

Similar to the all_expr in blend filter,

```
blend=all_expr='if(gte(Y-N*SH,0),A,B)'
```

Code ideas?